# Rails upload image can't be accessed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I upload an image to the Rails path`\public\upload\member\1.jpg`

but now  I can't access this image.

```
No route matches [GET] "/public/upload/member/20131030203910.jpg"
```

So,what should I do?

Comment: `<%= image_tag "upload/member/1.jpg" %>` try this, when does the error show up?

Comment: I just do this,but the issue is that I can't access the image

Comment: show the code, is there something with file permissions? It's difficult to understand your Question.

Comment: Rails is mvc,we access a file though a route,we can access an image in `\app\assets\images` but can't access an image in `/public/upload/member/20131030203910.jpg` just no route.

Comment: yes you are right, I'm using rails 2, so no assets. Try it from `Rails.root`

Comment: Thanks,`Rails.root` is just a physical path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= image_tag "/upload/member/1.jpg" %>` try that and also check is it really `upload` folder or maybe `uploads`

Answer (score 0):

better you can access the image using object 
`<%= object.image_url %>`